# E_INVALIDARG in D3D11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx-11

I have tried to figure out why I keep getting an E_INVALIDARG error when running my code.

```
    ID3D11Buffer * cbPerObjectBuffer;
cbPerObject cbPerObj;

cbPerObjectBuffer = 0;

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbbd;
ZeroMemory( & cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerObject);
cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;
cbbd.StructureByteStride = 0;

hr = device - > CreateBuffer( & cbbd, NULL, & cbPerObjectBuffer);
if (hr == E_INVALIDARG) {
  MessageBox(0, L "[CBPEROBJECTBUFFER] An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function.", L "Error", MB_OK);
  return;
} else if (hr == E_OUTOFMEMORY) {
  MessageBox(0, L "[CBPEROBJECTBUFFER] Out of memory", L "Error", MB_OK);
  return;
} else if (FAILED(hr)) {
  MessageBox(0, L "[CBPEROBJECTBUFFER] An unknown error occured", L "Error", MB_OK);
  return;
}
```

I keep getting the E_INVALIDARG error when running the code. I myself can't seem to figure out why I get this error.
If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be greatful! :)

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you might be able to find the solution by using the [debug layer (see MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj200584(v=vs.85).aspx) . Its diagnostic messages are usually quite useful.

Comment: Thank you. However I can't seem to figure out what to include to use the DX::ThrowIfFailed. Any ideas?

Comment: ThrowIfFailed is not necessary for that to work. The important part is the debug flag added to the creation call. It should then start writing messages to debug output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that 'cbPerObject' is not a multiple of 16 bytes. Constant Buffers must be a multiple of 16 bytes in size.

Comment: It seems like multiplying the ByteWidth with 16 fixed the problem.

Comment: Rounding up to the next multiple of 16 is what you need to do, not multiply by 16. if you multiply by 16 the constants buffers you create will be roughly 16 times too large and waste a lot of memory.

Comment: Would this method of rounding be efficient. cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerObject) + 16 - (sizeof(cbPerObject) % 16); ?